# in case of apache superset, what is the difference between gunicorn workers and celery workers

Tags: celery, gunicorn, apache-superset

In Superset's documentation, they are starting gunicorn workers and also celery workers with below commands:

```
gunicorn -w 3  -k gevent  --timeout 120  -b 0.0.0.0:8088  superset:app

celery --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app worker --pool=prefork -O fair -c 4
```

Can anyone explain what the difference between gunicorn workers and celery workers in the context of Superset?  That is, what tasks a gunicorn worker does and what a celery worker does.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Superset, being a web-service needs something to serve the clients connecting via their web-browsers - that is where gunicorn comes to the rescue. Those gunicorn workers are there to handle client requests.

Celery workers however are used to offload various tasks that may take either too long and/or need lot of resources (CPU power, disk space, etc). Typically Celery workers are distributed and Celery cluster scales up/down on demand.  In Superset, Celery workers can be told to send scheduled alerts and reports, visit dashboards and reports to take screenshots for these reports, fetch dashboard preview thumbnails, and warm up the cache of certain reports.